# how to change an item in IQueryable<T>?

Tags: c#, iqueryable

i have a the following class :

```
class myClass { string b; string c; string d; }
```

and the following list :

```
IQueryable<myClass> bla = new list<myClass>();
```

i want to change the first item in the list where myClass.c = "kitten";

To another instance of myClass lets call him newInstance;

i don't want to do  k = bla.first(x => x.c =="kitten")
and then copy one by one the fields from newInstance to k, i want the "bla" list to refernce to newInstance, without changing k..

how do i achieve it ?

Comment: `List<T>` doesn't implement `IQueryable<T>` - could you present a short but complete example which will compile?

Comment: private static IQueryable<Product> fakeProducts = new List<Product>  
            new Product { Name = "Football", Price = 25 }, 
            new Product { Name = "Surf board", Price = 179 }, 
            new Product { Name = "Running shoes", Price = 95 } 
        }.AsQueryable();

Comment: @OopsUser: Okay, so you're calling AsQueryable... any reason for doing so? Why bring IQueryable into the mix at all?

Comment: because many of my functions use the iqueryable interface.

Comment: @OopsUser: Do they need to though? What's `IQueryable<T>` giving you that `IEnumerable<T>` doesn't? It *may* be appropriate, but it may very well not be.

Comment: The book that i'm reading which teaching me mvc uses in his tutorial IQueryable .. 
This opens a door for another question, what is the difference between IQueryable , IEnumerable and some another similar interfaces and when should i use each of them

Comment: @OopsUser: IQueryable is usually used for out-of-process queries - e.g. to SQL databases. See http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2011/02/20/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-43-out-of-process-queries-with-iqueryable.aspx for more details.

Answer (score 1):

You can use below iterator to do this:

```
public static IEnumerable<myClass> GetChanged(IEnumerable<myClass> data)
{
    bool found = false;
    foreach(myClass c in data)
    {
       if(found == false && c.c=="kitten")
       {
           found = true;
           yield return new myClass() ; //new object
       }
       else
           yield return c;
    }
}
```